# Как добавить рандомайзер на основе js в html

Tags: javascript, html, случайные-числа

Знатоки js подскажите как оформить. Есть html:

```
<h5><a href="tel:+12345678900" id="chat"> +12-34-567-89-00 </a></h5>
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=12345678900" id="chat"></a>
<a href="viber://chat?number=12345678900" id="chat"></a>
```

Нужно номер телефона во все три тега подставлять рандомно, т.е одну из этих переменных a=12345678900, b=00123456789, c=98765432100.
В Python это делается с помощью модуля random:

```
a=['12345678900', '00123456789', '98765432100']
tel=a[random.randint(0,2)]
```

Как это сделать с помощью js и как переменную tel вставить в вышеуказанный html?

Comment: Math.random() функция

Comment: Я не понял, вам нужно рандомные цифры подставить в рандомные ячейки каждый раз или цифры рандомные сделать, что бы потом их подставить?

Comment: @peter есть три номера телефона, нужно один из них рандомно подставить в три тега а, учитывая что на странице еще есть теги а

Comment: @Jean-Claude `Math.floor(Math.random()*NUMBER)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ваш html сюда
```

```js
const nodeL = document.querySelectorAll('a');  

const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 

for (let node of nodeL) {   
    const href = node.href;
        node.href = href + getRandom(0000, 99999);
}
```

Однако на практике будет приблизительно такое.

```js
  const nodeL = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  const hrefs = [ 
    {
      path: { 
        text: "tel:",  
        href: '+' 
      } 
    }, 
    { 
      path: { 
        text: 'whatsapp', 
        href: '://send?phone'
      }, 
    },  
    { 
      path: { 
        text: 'viber', 
        href: '://chat?number'
      }
    } 
  ] 

  hrefs.forEach(({path}, index) => { 
    nodeL[index].href = `${path.text}${path.href}${getRandom(1e9, 1e9)}`;
  });
```